# Reading a remote text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a scenario where i need to read a TEXT file in a remote server and write the read data to another server.

I'm using the below code ,But do not know what modification need to do for accessing and reading a remote file and write it to destination server.In my local the query is working fine.

My source server is MySQL and destination is PostgreSQL.

Any leads will be of great help.

```
import psycopg2
import time
import os
import MySQLdb
from utils.config import Configuration as Config
from utils.postgres_helper import get_connection
from utils.utils import get_global_config

start_time = time.perf_counter()

#Magento connection 
try:
    source_host = 'mag'
    conf = get_global_config()
    cnx_msql = MySQLdb.connect(host=conf.get(source_host, 'host'),
                               user=conf.get(source_host, 'user'),
                               passwd=conf.get(source_host, 'password'),
                               port=int(conf.get(source_host, 'port')),
                               db=conf.get(source_host, 'db'))
    print ("Source Connected")
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
   print ("MYSQL: Unable to connect!", e.msg)
   sys.exit(1)

# Postgresql connection
 try:
   cnx_psql = get_connection(get_global_config(), 'pg_dwh')
   print ("DWH Connected")
 except psycopg2.Error as e:
   print('PSQL: Unable to connect!\n{0}').format(e)
   sys.exit(1)


# Cursors initializations
 cur_msql = cnx_msql.cursor()
 cur_psql = cnx_psql.cursor()

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        # Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
        quit()        
try:

    #filePath='''/Users/linu/Downloads/log''' 
    filePath='''/deft/log/final/log.txt''' 
    table='staging.stock_dump'

    SQL="""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS """+  table + """;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """+ table + """
      (created_date TEXT, product_sku TEXT, previous_stock TEXT, current_stock TEXT );"""

    cur_psql.execute(SQL)
    cnx_psql.commit()

    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
         for line in file:
           if 'Stock:' in line:
            fields=line.split(" ")
            date_part1=fields[0]
            date_part2=fields[1][:-1]
            sku=fields[3]
            prev_stock=fields[5]
            current_stock=fields[7]
            if prev_stock.strip()==current_stock.strip():
                continue
            else:
               cur_psql.execute("insert into " + table+"(created_date, product_sku, previous_stock , current_stock)" + " select CAST('" + date_part1+ " "+ date_part2 + "' AS TEXT)" +", CAST('"+sku+"' AS TEXT),CAST('" + prev_stock +"' AS TEXT),CAST('" +current_stock  + "' AS TEXT);")

    cnx_psql.commit()       
    cur_psql.close()
    cnx_psql.close()
    print("Data loaded to DWH from text file")
    print("Data porting took %s seconds to finish---" % (time.perf_counter() - start_time))

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Error adding  information.")
        quit()
```

Comment: Write a code to request the source file from the remote server to your machine using `requests` module and save it with the same location as in `filePath`.

Comment: @RajanChauhan So i have to copy the source file to my destination server right? Then only i will be able to read it? or Is there any other way? And do i need to connect the source via SSH?

Comment: Yes you can also copy file to your local path via ssh.

Comment: @RajanChauhan What is the best optimal way to do this? i don't want to copy the file from source server to destination server each and every time,I only need to read the content from  the TEXT file which is in source server and write those data to my PostgreSQL database in the destination.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If instead of text file you could maintain a `.sql` file then it is nothing but copying the file from the remote server via ssh and executing the sql file via [https://superuser.com/questions/701415/how-do-i-execute-run-a-sql-file-in-postgresql-9-2-6-centos](here) and programatically use python `subprocess` module to execute these as shell command.
You can create a cronjob utility for executing this on the target machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to read data from the Mysql (Magento) server and write it to the Postgresql server, yes? Instead of reading in a text file, you need to run a SQL query against the Mysql server, do any transform needed on the schema and types of the returned data, and then do an insert per record into Postgresql. If you are doing large amounts of data, then there are bulk load options to explore.

Comment: The file which i need to read is in the Magento server and i need to read that TEXT file and read it's content and write certain values to my PostgreSQL database.The TEXT file in Magento server will be around 20-30 MB in size.

Comment: Ok, then you need to get the file using something like the Requests library or SCP. Depends on how it is exposed on the Magento server. Once you have the file locally, your existing logic should work. With that much data, doing an insert per record will be slow.

Comment: so 'm planning to schedule it as a job every 30 minutes,So each time i need to copy the source text file to destination server and process it? is there any other better way to do this?  Also can you suggest what i need to do for improvement?